# When changing the cascading behavior of an FK in my database need to update model?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I work on MVC project with entity framework database first and I change the cascading behavior on an existing relationship: on delete cascade, and another  one on delete set null.

Do I need to update the EF model with these changes, or will the old model continue to work?

Answer (score 1):

EF will try to keep it's in-memory objects in sync with the database rows by applying the cascading rules that have been configured in the model.

Therefore, while not strictly required, it's a best practice to keep your EF model and database synchronized on the cascading behaviors.  Otherwise EF can retain objects in memory that have been modified or deleted in the database.

see [Tip 33 – How cascade delete really works in EF](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/08/18/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef/)

and [Cascade Delete in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete)